# How to add additional "items" on a webform in Drupal 7

Tags: webforms

I would like to provide the option of creating additional text fields under the same Label, if necessary. In the form of an "Add another" button. So when this button is pressed, an additional textfield will appear underneath. So, much like adding unlimited attachments to a node for example.

Is this possible using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module [Webform Add More](http://drupal.org/project/webform_addmore) does similar thing,

> Webform Add More enables selected fieldsets to be initially hidden and
>   progressively shown with an Add more button, mimicking CCK multiple
>   fields. The approach was proposed by Bartezz, and code originally
>   implemented by span and kranklin [1](http://drupal.org/project/webform_addmore). This module adds a checkbox
>   setting to webform fieldset components to select which should have Add
>   more functionality, as well as an advanced setting to override the
>   button label per Webform.

Comment: Thank you @Anoop_Joseph

Does this module only make it possible to add one field at a time, or does it also make it possible to add additional SECTIONS/groups of fields?

Comment: It actually works in way that initially hidden and progressively shown.Check  [sample] (http://drupal.org/files/images/add_more_0.png)

Comment: Any idea how to fix this error message @anoop-joseph

Notice: Undefined index: label in webform_addmore_form_webform_configure_form_alter() (line 51 of /home/icac/public_html/sites/all/modules/webform_addmore/webform_addmore.module).

Comment: Check with module issue queue, a similar http://drupal.org/node/1934314

Answer (score 0):

The [Select (or other)](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_or_other) module provides the functionality similar (or identical?) to what you are looking for. Here is an excerpt about it from its project page.

> Provides a new Forms API element which is a select/radios/checkboxes element that has an 'other' option. When 'other' is selected a textfield appears for the user to provide a custom value.

Here is a sample about it:

[image]